# Pushing an array into another array?

Tags: javascript

I have an array:

```
var fileMetaData = [];
```

In a loop I want to push things to the array:

```
$('#gallery-manager-add-form .galleryImage').each(function(){

    fileMetaData.push(myTestArray);
});
```

For testing myTestArray is:

```
var myTestArray = new Array(2);
myTestArray['a'] = 'foo';
myTestArray['b'] = 'bar';
```

The problem is, when I get the contents of the array, it's just a comma (,).

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: I've put 2 jsfiddle demos up, one of them will be what you are after

Comment: ...but as `dystroy` pointed out, you should be using Objects not Arrays.

Answer (score 4):

That's because you're confusing arrays and objects (which you should use).

If your keys are `'a'` and `'b'`, use

```
var myTestArray = {};
myTestArray['a'] = 'foo';
myTestArray['b'] = 'bar';
```

If you really want to use an array, use

```
var myTestArray = [];
myTestArray.push('foo'); // no explicit key 
myTestArray.push('bar');
```

You saw just a comma because, the standard representation of an array doesn't look for properties, so you were printing the equivalent of `[[],[]].toString()` which is `","`.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays use numerical keys. You've used "a" and "b".

Initialise it like this:

```
var myTestArray = ['foo', 'bar'];
```

Alternatively, use this to keep your code almost the same:

```
var myTestArray = new Array(2);
myTestArray[0] = 'foo';
myTestArray[1] = 'bar';
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're assigning values to `myTestArray['a']` and `myTestArray['b']`, you're not pushing them into the array, but rather assigning the values to properties of the object. To treat the items as values in an array, you'd need to use the integer indexes, or just `push` them:

```
myTestArray[0] = 'foo';
myTestArray.push('bar');
```

But the other part, where you're pushing into the `fileMetaData` array - if you're trying to push both items from `myTestArray`, you'd need to do that differently - if you push one array into another, you're pushing the array, not the items. You'd need to either loop through one at a time and push them that way, or use something like `concat` to merge the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
$('#gallery-manager-add-form .galleryImage').each(function(){

    fileMetaData.push(myTestArray[0],myTestArray[1]);

});
```

1 dimensional array
http://jsfiddle.net/Gs6ZU/

2 dimensional array
http://jsfiddle.net/fY9S5/1/